# Loading GIF Icon not animating in Chrome or Any browser during AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax

Loading  GIF Icon not animating in Chrome or Any browser during AJAX call

Funtion which i call first:

```
    function Row(x) {
var threadID = x.parentNode.id;
var urlForActionComments = $("#GettingCommentsJSON").val();
var listOfComments;
$('#overLapContainer').append('<img id="loadingImage" src="../Resources/IMAGES/LoadingImage.gif" />');
$('#overLapContainer').show();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: urlForActionComments,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: { threadID: threadID },
    success:function(data)
    {
        //$('#replyContentDiv').css('display', 'block');
        listOfComments = data;
        setTimeout(appendingComments(listOfComments),100);
        //appendingComments(listOfComments);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Error While Fetching Likes for'+threadID)
    }
})
}


function appendingComments(listOfComments)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < listOfComments.length; i++) {
        var userMailID = listOfComments[i].CreatedByEmail;
        var newContent = imageForComment(userMailID); 
        commentRow = '<div class="commentNewContainer">\
        <div class="leftCommentNewContainer">\
             <input type="hidden" class="' + userMailID + '" />\
             <img id="' + i + '" src="#" />\
        </div>\
        <div class="rightCommentNewContainer"><span>' + listOfComments[i].CommentContent + '</span></div>\
    </div>';

        $('#commentContainerID').append(commentRow);
        var forMailid = '.leftCommentNewContainer' + ' ' + '#' + i;
        if (newContent != null) {
            $(forMailid).attr("src", "data:image/png;base64," + newContent);
        }
        else
        {
            $(forMailid).attr("src", "/Resources/IMAGES/default_user.png");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the function which is called some n number of times: from the above function:

```
function imageForComment(userMailID) {
var urlForFetchingImage = $('#FetchingPostUserImageviaEMailJSON').val();
var image = null;

setTimeout(
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: urlForFetchingImage,
     dataType: 'JSON',
     async: false,
     data: { email: userMailID },
     success: function (data) {
         //$('#replyContentDiv').css('display', 'block');
         ////debugger;
         image = data.ImageBytesAsString;
         //var idforImage = '#' + userMailID;
         //if (data.ImageBytesAsString != null) {
         //    $(idforImage).attr("src", "data:image/png;base64," + data.ImageBytesAsString);
         //}
         //else {
         //    $(idforImage).attr("src", "/Resources/IMAGES/default_user.png");
         //} 
     },
     error: function (ex) {
         alert(ex);
     }
 }), 100);
return image;
}
```

Before calling the appendingComments function i am making the gif icon to be loaded. and i am calling the imageForComment() function. But the GIF image is not loading as per my need.

Comment: you need to add more detail about html you're using.

Comment: Please add the rest of the code.  All we see is an Ajax post with a couple of `divs` being hidden.   You are also missing 2 semicolons `;`.  One after the `alert` line, and one at the very end.

Comment: I am calling this AJAX function some n number of times. Before the AJAX call i am making the GIF icon to be visible. But its not loading/ animating. It justs appears as a static .jpg. After the ajax call gif hides as usual

Comment: Please provide the code where you are making the GIF visible. Both HTML and JS

Comment: Updated the code. both HTML and JS